# How to view a post from the wordpress admin screen

Tags: posts, wp-admin, dashboard

I have been thinking of displaying my post from the admin dashboard screen just like how a plugin is displayed.
[image: sample image]

Above is a wordpress dashboard. How do i view post from the wp screen. Kindly help me. without being redirected to the post url I'll appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the functions

```
///Show on the counter
function my_custom_dashboard_widgets() { 
global $wp_meta_boxes;
wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_help_widget', 'Posts','custom_dashboard_help');
}
function custom_dashboard_help() {
$randoms= new WP_Query(array(
'post_type'=>'post','post_status'=>'publish','order'=>'DESC','orderby'=>'ID',
'posts_per_page'=>'10'));
if($randoms->have_posts()) : while($randoms->have_posts()) : $randoms->the_post();?>
<!----post---->
<div class="img-in" style="width: 96%;height: 60px;margin-bottom: 7px;background-color: bisque;padding: 9px;">
<img src="<?php
$thumb_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
$thumb_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($thumb_id,'thumbnail-size', true);
echo $thumb_url[0];
?>" alt=""  style="width: 50px;float: right;height: 50px;"> 
<div style="margin-right: 54px;">
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank" ><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>
  <br>
<span style="font-size: 12px;"><a href="<?php bloginfo('url');?>/wp-admin/post.php?post=<?php the_ID(); ?>&action=edit"style="color: blue;" target="_blank" > edit </a> </span> 
</div>
</div>
<!----/post---->
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query();
 } add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'my_custom_dashboard_widgets');
```

[image]